# How to send mail based on from email address using smtp c#

Tags: c#-3.0

We want to send email using from email address instead of smtp email address...
I tried to send mail where from email address and smtp authenticated email address are different. 
It gives me error.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you are trying to send a message from say "ned@yourdomain.com" by authenticating as "you@yourdomain.com" - Normaly people configure SMTP servers to not allow this due to SPAM and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can based on the following code below. Hope it helps

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com", "Subject"); // You can try changing this to the email address you want
mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("sender@domain.com"); // Here you can add reply to
mailMessage.Subject = "ENQUIRY - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
mailMessage.Body = ""; // The body of email
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.company-domain.com");
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
smtpClient.Port = 587; // We used this port instead of port 25
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```